# Why UDP does not work after analogRead() on esp8266-12N module?

Tags: esp8266, analogread

Consider my loop() in Arduino be:

```
void loop(){
  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
   Value[i] = analogRead(A0);
   delayMicroseconds(62);
  }
   //delay(2) //when I use this line esp8266 works properly
   Udp.beginPacket(IP, Port);
   Udp.write(Value, 100);
   Udp.endPacket();
}
```

after analogRead() UDP can't send packets and crash occur after a moment. But when I use `delay(2)` line in the above code it works properly. I want to record samples of microphone with `16000` sample rate and I use `62` microseconds for this. Thus in my application it is not possible for delay 2 milliseconds. How can I fix this without delay?

Comment: hard use of A0 disturbs WiFi signal measuring done by SDK with the same ADC. use external ADC for continues measurement with esp8266

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Comment: +1 for the excellent answer Juraj. I did not know that hard use of the ADC would cause issues with the WiFi signal :)